# The Images Generated by WGAN-GP Looks Very Gray

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, computer-vision, generative-adversarial-network

This is a **solved** problem, the reason is due to the high resolution.

---

Everyone, below is the images generated by my WGAN-GP, but it looks not colourful? I don't know how to describe it, btw, the loss is always increasing......

[image: Results]

[image: Train]

The Data is:

```
def data_preprocess():
    
    batch_size = 64

    data_transforms = transforms.Compose([transforms.Resize(size=(256,256)), transforms.ToTensor(), transforms.Normalize([0.5, 0.5, 0.5],[0.5, 0.5, 0.5])])
    
    data_dir = "./256"
    data = ImageFolder(data_dir,transform = data_transforms)
    data_loader = Data.DataLoader(
        data,
        batch_size = batch_size,
        shuffle = True,
        num_workers = 0)
    
    return data_loader, data, batch_size
```

For G and D:

```
class Generator(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.main = nn.Sequential( # Z: 100
            
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(100, 1024, 4, 2, 0),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(num_features=1024),
            nn.ReLU(True),

            nn.ConvTranspose2d(1024, 512, 4, 2, 1),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(num_features=512),
            nn.ReLU(True),

            nn.ConvTranspose2d(512, 256, 4, 2, 1),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(num_features=256),
            nn.ReLU(True),

            nn.ConvTranspose2d(256, 128, 4, 2, 1),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(num_features=128),
            nn.ReLU(True),

            nn.ConvTranspose2d(128, 64, 4, 2, 1),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(num_features=64),
            nn.ReLU(True),

            nn.ConvTranspose2d(64, 32, 4, 2, 1),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(num_features=32),
            nn.ReLU(True), # nn.ReLU(True)

            nn.ConvTranspose2d(32, 3, 4, 2, 1)) # Output of Main: (3,256,256)

        self.output = nn.Tanh()
        
    def weight_init(self,type):
        if type == "default":
            for m in self.main:
                if isinstance(m, nn.Conv2d):
                    nn.init.normal_(m.weight.data, 0, 0.02)
                elif isinstance(m, nn.BatchNorm2d):
                    nn.init.normal_(m.weight.data, 0, 0.02)
                    nn.init.constant_(m.bias.data, 0)
        elif type == "kaiming":
            for m in self.main:
                if isinstance(m, nn.Conv2d):
                    nn.init.kaiming_normal_(m.weight.data, a=0, mode='fan_in', nonlinearity='relu')
                elif isinstance(m, nn.BatchNorm2d):
                    nn.init.normal_(m.weight.data, 0, 0.02)
                    nn.init.constant_(m.bias.data, 0)
        elif type == "xavier":
            for m in self.main:
                if isinstance(m, nn.Conv2d):
                    nn.init.xavier_normal_(m.weight.data, gain=1.0)
                elif isinstance(m, nn.BatchNorm2d):
                    nn.init.normal_(m.weight.data, 0, 0.02)
                    nn.init.constant_(m.bias.data, 0)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.main(x)
        return self.output(x)

class Discriminator(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.main = nn.Sequential(

            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=3, out_channels=32, kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=1), # (3,256,256)
            nn.LayerNorm((128,128)),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True),
            
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=32, out_channels=64, kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=1),
            # nn.BatchNorm2d(64),
            nn.LayerNorm((64,64)),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True),

            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=64, out_channels=128, kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=1),
            # nn.BatchNorm2d(128),
            nn.LayerNorm((32,32)),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True),

            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=128, out_channels=256, kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=1),
            # nn.BatchNorm2d(256),
            nn.LayerNorm((16,16)),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True),

            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=256, out_channels=512, kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=1),
            # nn.BatchNorm2d(512),
            nn.LayerNorm((8,8)),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True),

            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=512, out_channels=1024, kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=1), # (1024,4,4)
            # nn.BatchNorm2d(1024),
            nn.LayerNorm((4,4)),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True))

        self.output = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=1024, out_channels=1, kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=0) # 1
            # nn.Sigmoid()
            )
        
    def weight_init(self,type):
        if type == "default":
            for m in self.main:
                if isinstance(m, nn.Conv2d):
                    nn.init.normal_(m.weight.data, 0, 0.02)
                elif isinstance(m, nn.LayerNorm):
                    nn.init.normal_(m.weight.data, 0, 0.02)
                    nn.init.constant_(m.bias.data, 0)
        elif type == "kaiming":
            for m in self.main:
                if isinstance(m, nn.Conv2d):
                    nn.init.kaiming_normal_(m.weight.data, a=0, mode='fan_in', nonlinearity='leaky_relu')
                elif isinstance(m, nn.LayerNorm):
                    nn.init.normal_(m.weight.data, 0, 0.02)
                    nn.init.constant_(m.bias.data, 0)
        elif type == "xavier":
            for m in self.main:
                if isinstance(m, nn.Conv2d):
                    nn.init.xavier_normal_(m.weight.data, gain=1.0)
                elif isinstance(m, nn.LayerNorm):
                    nn.init.normal_(m.weight.data, 0, 0.02)
                    nn.init.constant_(m.bias.data, 0)
                    
    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.main(x)suggestion
        return self.output(x)
```

The GP function:

```
def calculate_gradient_penalty(real_images, fake_images):
    
    t = torch.rand(real_images.size(0), 1, 1, 1).to(real_images.device)
    t = t.expand(real_images.size())

    interpolates = t * real_images + (1 - t) * fake_images
    interpolates.requires_grad_(True)

    disc_interpolates = D(interpolates)

    grad = torch.autograd.grad(outputs=disc_interpolates, 
                               inputs=interpolates,
                               grad_outputs=torch.ones_like(disc_interpolates),
                               create_graph=True, 
                               retain_graph=True)[0]

    loss_gp = (((grad.norm(2, dim=1) - 1) ** 2).mean()) * lambda_term # grad.norm(order, dim)
   
    return loss_gp
```

Finally the Training Part:

```
G = Generator()
D = Discriminator()
G.weight_init("kaiming") # "default", "kaiming", "xavier"
D.weight_init("kaiming")
G.to(device)
D.to(device)

learning_rate = 1e-4 # 1e-4
lambda_term = 10
generator_iters = 10000
data_preprocess.batch_size = 64
critic_iter = 5 # 1 Generator, 5 Discriminator
record_lenth = 0

# loss = nn.BCELoss().to(device) # No Log Here
d_optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(D.parameters(), lr=learning_rate, betas=(0.5, 0.999))
g_optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(G.parameters(), lr=learning_rate, betas=(0.5, 0.999))
data_loader, data, batch_size = data_preprocess()

d_progress = []
d_fake_progress = []
d_real_progress = []
penalty = []
g_progress = []

data = get_infinite_batches(data_loader)
one = torch.FloatTensor([1]).to(device) 
mone = (one * -1).to(device) 

for g_iter in range(generator_iters):
    
    print('----------G Iter-{}----------'.format(g_iter+1))
    
    for p in D.parameters():
        p.requires_grad = True # This is by Default
        
    d_loss_real = 0
    d_loss_fake = 0
    Wasserstein_D = 0

    for d_iter in range(critic_iter):
        D.zero_grad()
            
        images = data.__next__()
        if images.size()[0] != batch_size:
            continue
        
        # Train Discriminator
        # Real Images
        images = images.to(device)
        z = torch.randn(batch_size, 100, 1, 1).to(device)
        d_real = D(images)
        d_loss_real = d_real.mean(0).view(1)
        d_loss_real.backward(mone)
        
        # Fake Images
        z = torch.randn(batch_size, 100, 1, 1).to(device) # ???
        fake_images = G(z)
        d_fake = D(fake_images)
        d_loss_fake = d_fake.mean(0).view(1)
        d_loss_fake.backward(one)
        
        # Calculate Penalty
        gradient_penalty = calculate_gradient_penalty(images.data, fake_images.data)
        gradient_penalty.backward()
        
        # Total Loss
        d_loss = d_loss_fake - d_loss_real + gradient_penalty
        Wasserstein_D = d_loss_real - d_loss_fake
        d_optimizer.step()
        print('D Loss: %.6s, Fake: %.6s, Real: %.6s, Penalty: %.6s' %(d_loss.item(),d_loss_fake.item(),d_loss_real.item(),gradient_penalty.item())) 
        
        time.sleep(0.1)
        d_progress.append(d_loss.item()) # Store Loss
        d_fake_progress.append(d_loss_fake.item())
        d_real_progress.append(d_loss_real.item())
        penalty.append(gradient_penalty.item())
        
        record_lenth += 1
        writer.add_scalars('Continue Test D Loss', {'D Loss': d_loss, # Multiply in One
                                 'D Loss Fake': d_loss_fake,
                                 'D Loss Real': d_loss_real}, record_lenth+1)
    
    # Generator Updata
    for p in D.parameters():
        p.requires_grad = False  # Avoid Computation
    
    # Train Generator
    # Compute with Fake
    G.zero_grad()
    z = torch.randn(batch_size, 100, 1, 1).to(device)
    fake_images = G(z)
    d_fake = D(fake_images)
    g_loss = d_fake.mean(0).view(1)
    g_loss.backward(mone) 
    g_cost = -g_loss
    g_optimizer.step()
    print('G Loss: %.6s'% g_loss.item()) 
        
    g_progress.append(g_loss.item()) # Store Loss
    writer.add_scalar('Continue Test G Loss', g_loss, g_iter+1) # Tensor Board
```

I don't know why this happens, I had tried to train more iterations - 10000 iterations and nothing becomes better...... I will still try my best to solve this problem, but I am new in GAN so should anyone have any suggestions, pls let me know, thx in advance! Hoping everyone has a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

You are applying the following transform:

```
transforms.Normalize([0.5, 0.5, 0.5],[0.5, 0.5, 0.5])
```

Since the transform right before is [`transforms.ToTensor`](https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/transforms.html?highlight=totensor#torchvision.transforms.ToTensor), which will output values in the `[0, 1]` range. And considering you are using [`transforms.Normalize`](https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/transforms.html?highlight=normalize#torchvision.transforms.Normalize) with mean `0.5` and std `0.5`, your input images will end up in the [-1, 1] range which might explain the gray look on your images. Depending on your dataset and whether you are using batch norms or not, it might be worth changing those values to reflect your dataset's statistics.

Comment: Thx for your fast reply! I will try now but it's strange that on DCGAN, the generated image looks normal, no matter how I will try first.

Answer (score 0):

I had also met with such problem when training my GAN models, it's pretty usual but it worked out for me even using the same data preprocessing(e.g. `Normalize([.5,.5,.5],[.5,.5,.5])`).

I suspect it's related to the optimization process of the model(especially with GANs) mainly from two aspects:

1. the Generator are prone to produce poor images, at early phase of the training(cuz the results are easy to be distinguished by the Discriminator);
2. if it happened at later phase of the training(meaning when loss for the Generator already decreased till the flat tail of an exponentially decreasing loss curve), then it's like to be a reason of close-optima oscillation, but in this case you will observe good result show up interspersed with poor results;

Anyway, GANs produce sharp results but are fragile to tune, good luck and play more around with different normalization layers, optimization tricks.